How to organize the receive msg and user current input in C network such that it's clean
The program has two threads, one to handle send, one to handle recv. User will always be prompted with fgets() to input message for send. Meanwhile, the recv thread will display the message sent to the user.
When a message is received while the user is half-way through the composition of the message, things get meshed up like:
>>I'm composing a me<new message>ssage

I think this problem roots from input and output is at the same window.  Is there any way to make it cleaner such that the new message will be separated from user's current input?
My current recv and send code goes
void* talk(void* sockfd){
    char msg[MSG_LEN_LIMIT];

    while(1){
        //printf("me: ");
        fgets(msg, MSG_LEN_LIMIT, stdin);
        msg[strcspn(msg, "\n")] = 0;
        send(*((int*)sockfd), msg, MSG_LEN_LIMIT, 0);
        //printf("me: %s\n", msg);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* listento(void *sockfd){
    int byteReceived;
    char msg[MSG_LEN_LIMIT];

    while(1){
        if((byteReceived = recv(*((int*)sockfd), msg, MSG_LEN_LIMIT, 0) )== -1){
            perror("recv");
            continue;
        }else if(byteReceived == 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "connection lost");
            exit(1);
        }
        //msg[byteReceived] = '\0';
        printf("otherside: %s\n", msg);
    }
}


update, I looked into ncurses library mentioned by @grawity_u1686 and @Awayy. After some head scratching learning, I finally implemented a functional text interface with ncurses.
The corresponding code goes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#define CLIENTPORT "4000"
#define SERVERPORT "3490"
#define MSG_LEN_LIMIT 256
#define BACKLOG 10
#define PAD_LENGTH 100

pthread_t threads[2];

typedef struct s_threadArgs{
    int *sockfd;
    WINDOW *pad;
    int maxRow;
    int maxCol;
    int *pad_top;
    int *pad_left;
    int *writeLine;
    
} threadArgs;

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int sendAll(int sockdf, char *buf, int bufLen){
    int total = 0;
    int byteLeft = bufLen;
    int byteSent;

    while(total < bufLen){
        if( (byteSent = send(sockdf, buf+total, byteLeft, 0) )  == -1 ){
            return -1;
        }
        total +=byteSent;
        byteLeft -=byteSent;
    }

    return byteSent==-1?-1:0;
}

int tryConenct(char *connectAddr){
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr their_addr;
    int rv, numbytes;
    
    char msg[MSG_LEN_LIMIT];


    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if( (rv = getaddrinfo(connectAddr, SERVERPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return -1;
    }

    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next){
        if( (sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1 ){
            perror("socket");
            continue;
        }

        if( connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1 ){
            close(sockfd);
            perror("connect");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    if(p == NULL){

        fprintf(stderr, "talker: socket failed\n");
        return -2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
    //close(sockfd);
    return sockfd;
}

int spinServer(){
    int sockfd, new_fd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    int rv;
    int yes = 1;
    int numbytes;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    char buf[MSG_LEN_LIMIT];
    socklen_t addr_len;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, SERVERPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return -1;
    }

    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next){
        if((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1){
            perror("socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1){
            perror("bind failed");
            close(sockfd);
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if(p == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "listener: failed to bin socket\n");
        return -2;
    }

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        return -3;
    }

    printf("listener: waiting to receive...\n");

    addr_len = sizeof their_addr;

    addr_size = sizeof their_addr;
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size);
    if(new_fd == -1){
        perror("accept");
        return -4;
    }

    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family, get_in_addr( (struct sockaddr*)&their_addr ), s, sizeof s);
    printf("me: accepted incomming connection from %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
    close(sockfd);
    return new_fd;
}

void* talk(void* args){
    char msg[MSG_LEN_LIMIT];
    threadArgs *targs = (threadArgs*)args;
    int visible_height = targs->maxRow - 2;
    int visible_width = targs->maxCol - 2;
    int pad_height = PAD_LENGTH;
    int pad_width = targs->maxCol - 2;

    if(targs->pad == NULL){
        printf("pad not available in talk\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getch()) != 'q') {
        switch (ch) {
            case KEY_UP:
                if (*(targs->pad_top) > 0) (*(targs->pad_top))--;
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                if (*(targs->pad_top) + visible_height < pad_height) (*(targs->pad_top))++;
                break;
            // case KEY_LEFT:
            //     if (pad_left > 0) pad_left--;
            //     break;
            // case KEY_RIGHT:
            //     if (pad_left + visible_width < pad_width) pad_left++;
            //     break;
            case 'a':
                echo();
                move((targs->maxRow)-1, 0);
                clrtoeol();
                refresh();
                mvprintw((targs->maxRow) - 1, 0, ":");
                mvgetstr((targs->maxRow) - 1, 2,  msg);
                send(*( targs->sockfd ), msg, MSG_LEN_LIMIT, 0);
                //integrate the first letter to rest of msg
                mvwprintw(targs->pad, *(targs->writeLine), 0, "me: %s", msg);
                clrtoeol();
                refresh();
                noecho();
                (*(targs->writeLine))++;
                move((targs->maxRow)-1, 0);
                if (*(targs->writeLine) > visible_height) (*(targs->pad_top))++;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // Display the pad content within the visible window
        prefresh(targs->pad, (*(targs->pad_top)), (*(targs->pad_left)), 0, 0, visible_height, visible_width);
    }

    delwin(targs->pad);
    endwin();
    return NULL;
}

void* listento(void *args){
    int byteReceived;
    char msg[MSG_LEN_LIMIT];

    threadArgs *targs = (threadArgs*)args;
    int visible_height = targs->maxRow - 2;
    int visible_width = targs->maxCol - 2;
    int pad_height = PAD_LENGTH;
    int pad_width = targs->maxCol - 2;

    if(targs->pad == NULL){
        printf("pad not available in talk\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1){
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
        if((byteReceived = recv(*( targs->sockfd ), msg, MSG_LEN_LIMIT, 0) )== -1){
            perror("recv");
            continue;
        }else if(byteReceived == 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "\nconnection lost");
            exit(1);
        }
        //msg[byteReceived] = '\0';
        //printf("otherside: %s\n", msg);
        mvwprintw(targs->pad, *(targs->writeLine), 0, "they: %s", msg);
        (*(targs->writeLine))++;
        if (*(targs->writeLine) > visible_height) (*(targs->pad_top))++;
        prefresh(targs->pad, (*(targs->pad_top)), (*(targs->pad_left)), 0, 0, visible_height, visible_width);

    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sockfd;
    bool isServer;
    char msg[MSG_LEN_LIMIT];
    int *fd = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    //establish connection
    char ipAddr[] = "::1";
    if((sockfd = tryConenct(ipAddr)) < 0){
        //failed to connect, spin up the listenning procedure, this client will serve as server
        sockfd = spinServer();
        if(sockfd < 0){
            printf("server spin: failed\n");
            return 1;
        }else{
            printf("accepted: sockfd %d\n", sockfd);
            isServer = true;
        }
    }else{
        printf("connected, sockfd %d\n", sockfd);
        isServer = false;
    }
    
    //connection established, communication begins
    *fd = sockfd;

    //pad setup
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    int rows, cols, writeLine;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, rows, cols);
    int pad_height = 100;
    int pad_width = cols - 2;
    WINDOW *pad = newpad(pad_height, pad_width);
    if (pad == NULL) {
        endwin();
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pad\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int pad_top = 0;
    int pad_left = 0;
    writeLine = 0;

    mvprintw(rows - 1, 0, "type 'a' for messaging , 'q' to quit: ");
    refresh();

    threadArgs *tArgs = (threadArgs*)malloc(sizeof(threadArgs));
    tArgs->maxCol = cols;
    tArgs->maxRow = rows;
    tArgs->pad = pad;
    tArgs->pad_left = &pad_left;
    tArgs->pad_top = &pad_top;
    tArgs->writeLine = &writeLine;
    tArgs->sockfd = fd;


    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, &talk, tArgs);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, &listento, tArgs);
    
    pthread_join(threads[0], NULL);
    pthread_cancel(threads[1]);
    pthread_join(threads[1], NULL);



    return 0;
}

Input box now always stays at the bottom of the terminal, while sent and received messages will be displayed in a scrollable fashion using up/down arrows. Thank you guys for suggesting this library!

Can you name a message app that uses a single window?

I mean, this message app is meant for 2 clients, each having its own window(terminal box). Say Alice and Bob messaging each other. In Alice perspective, she's composed some words, haven't sent yet. Then Bob sent a msg to her, and the message bob sent got printed straight appending alice's half composed message

Have you used Google Chat, MS Teams, Slack, WhatsApp, or any similar chat program?  Have you observed how they do it?  Why don't you do what those do?  Even in a text-based application (rather than a GUI like the exemplars), you can arrange for the received messages to be queued for display until immediately after the user hits return to finish their input.  You might want to record the times of arrival and display them.  But if you have complete control over the screen (using a curses-style interactive application rather than just fgets()) you can do better.

I see what you guys mean by the mistake of using only one window. You're right, I can't really think of any msg app that only uses 1 window. "curses-style interactive application" could be a sound solution! I looked it up and curses library pops up, like @Awayy 's answer.

@JonathanLeffler: "arrange for the received messages to be queued for display until immediately after the user hits return to finish their input" really doesn't sound like a pleasant user experience. Have you seen any of the aforementioned chat apps delay showing received messages until the user hits "Send" first?

@grawity_u1686: I didn’t say it would be a good UX.  It would (probably) achieve the separation of messages and responses.  But taking full control of the display is best.

Input and output being on the same terminal window is definitely the root of the problem, you're bound to run into I/O stream collisions doing it like this. I would look into using ncurses to split your terminal view into two windows possibly an input window at the bottom and an output window at the top, that choice is left up to you :P

Thanks! Ncurses certainly is a potential solution to my problem! I'll circle back after I try that.


I think this problem roots from input and output is at the same window. Is there any way to make it cleaner such that the new message will be separated from user's current input?

Instead of reading lines from the terminal in cooked mode with plain fgets() and relying on the terminal's almost-nonexistent editing support, I would suggest switching to a full line-editing library such as editline, tecla, or readline – the latter is what Bash uses.
In-process line editing means that the program receives input character-by-character, and already knows what's entered before the user presses Enter. As well as giving you all of the usual text-editing keyboard shortcuts, using in-process line editing lets you clear the whole thing from display, then output a received message, then re-display the prompt with the text pre-filled (and still editable!).
Not all libraries make this convenient; e.g. with readline, the clearing may need to be done manually, although it does provide a redisplay() function that you'd call after output. Unfortunately I don't have any particular suggestions as to what specific library would work better. I see that the Linenoise library has specific support for this use case, but that's just what I found on Google right now.

Finally, instead of the prompt-based UI, you could redesign the app to become a "full-screen" (well, full-terminal) app, in the style of IRC clients such as Irssi or WeeChat. This is most commonly done using the curses C library or its derivative ncurses, although many alternatives exist (slang used to be common, notcurses can get really fancy; one example for Golang rather than C is bubbletea).
Doing so would give you full control over what's displayed on the (terminal) screen and where, including even mouse support – although at the cost of losing terminal-provided text scrolling (you have to implement your own "scrollback").
But sometimes the "full screen" approach (via ncurses and such) can be more reliable, in particular when user input wraps to multiple lines, as the "readline/editline" approach needs to keep track of where the prompt started using relative positioning and avoid erasing too much or too little of the terminal's scrollback, whereas in "full screen" mode the ncurses library can just redisplay the whole thing.

This "in-process line editing" sounds like what I imagined! Like the input prompt always automatically squeeze to the bottom. I'll certainly look into it, thanks!

That is not necessarily automatic, it just gives you the possibility of implementing that. (Although, as others suggest, a "full screen" chat app using curses/ncurses/slang/similar is certainly more common and would give you much more flexibility (at the cost of losing terminal-based scrollback) – but "prompt-based" interactive apps with such prompting have existed in the past, both for chat and non-chat purposes.)
